# Python Tkinter background

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

```
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=800, height=600, bg="black") # PEP8: space after comma
canvas.pack()
```

Do anyone know how I could import a image from google to set as a background in canvas?

Answer (score 1):

First, download the image as a `.png`. If you have the latest version of tkinter, then the following will work.

Write this code:

```py
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=800, height=600, bg="black") # PEP8: space after 
canvas.pack()
p = tk.PhotoImage(file = "putyourimagenamehere.png")
canvas.create_image(100, 100, image = p)
```

For the above code to work, you need to put the image in the same directory as the `.py` file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It says that PhotoImage is not defined, any clue why?

Comment: If you imported tkinter as `import tkinter as tk` it should be `tk.PhotoImage`